# Memory allocation error trying to create a map with eurostat package with R

Tags: r, memory, dplyr

I am trying to download the data from eurostat using eurostat package with R.

The dataset can be downloaded by specificifying its "code_id", which in this case is: **"edat_lfse_33"**

However, I got stuck because when I try to run the code below, my computer crashes/returns a Memory allocation Error.

```
    library(eurostat)
    library(dplyr)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(stringr)

    data=get_eurostat("edat_lfse_33")
```

That returns a huge tibble as following:

```
    # A tibble: 2,914,673 x 8
    unit  sex   isced11 duration age    geo    time values
    <fct> <fct> <fct>   <fct>    <fct>  <fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
    1 PC    F     ED0-2   TOTAL    Y15-34 AT     2018   49.9
    2 PC    F     ED0-2   TOTAL    Y15-34 AT1    2018   48.4

                               (..)
```

Then once I try to join the previous tibble object using get_eurostat_geospatial, my pc gets crashes.

```
    mapdata <- get_eurostat_geospatial(nuts_level = 2, resolution='60',
                                       year=2016, 
                                       output_class = 'df') %>%
      right_join(data)%>%
      mutate(cat = cut_to_classes(values, n=2, decimals = 1))
```

Could someone help me out?

Comment: What's your expected "by" column for joining? Leave it up to R to decide?

Comment: It tries to join the two objects based on the geo code. When I run the script it prints in the console "joining by geo code" and then it gets stuck.

Comment: The only common column is `geo` and both tables have multiple duplicates. it's not surprising that your computer crashes.

Comment: You may need to _summarise_ the large `data` table first somehow, grouping by `geo`. For example, the mean of the `values` or the number of records for each `geo`. Then merge with the mapdata table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't join two data table when both of them contain duplicates on the join column. The mapdata is OK because it contains the map data in the correct format for ggplot but the data table needs to be summarized before you can be joined.

```
data2 <- data %>% 
  group_by(geo) %>%
  summarise(Values=mean(values, na.rm=TRUE))

library(ggplot2)
data2 %>% right_join(mapdata, by="geo") %>%
  #mutate(cat = cut_to_classes(Values, n=2, decimals = 1)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lat, long, group=group)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=Values))
```

[image]

Comment: Super!! Thank you very much!